# Extended Security Maintenance (ESM) Audit

Tags: security, esm

I have run into a strange situation I was hoping someone could help with.  I have an audit being run on our appliance running Ubuntu 12.04 ESM.  I am told the the ESM version of Ubuntu is installed but I need to prove this to our Secuirty audit team.

Does anyone know of a command or way to prove that ESM is installed?

Comment: What level of proof are you looking for? Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and `/var/lib/apt/lists` folder will have `esm` repos in. `lsb_release -a` should say you're on 12.04 and ESM. `ubuntu-advantage status` should indicate ESM is enabled. But it might be pertinent just to ask the [ESM support team](https://www.ubuntu.com/support/esm) if you're needing some sort of proof of wider system status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ubuntu-advantage status` gives the current status of a system wrt to ESM and other [Ubuntu Advantage](https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/ubuntu-advantage) offerings.

Comment: Thank you!  This should provide the information we need.  I greatly appreciate your help!!